# Force games stretch into full screen in lower resolution?

Tags: windows-7, gaming, scaling, stretch

I am playing Mortal Kombat Komplete Edition on Windows 7. I can't run with my max resolution (1680x1050) because my video card doesn't have enough power to support 60 fps (ATI Radeon HD2600 Pro) so I decide to edit the configure file to make it run at 1024x640 (still keep the ratio 8:5 same as 1680x1050's).

This is the problem : the game runs but it doesn't stretch to full screen, there is a black box around it. So is there way to force the game stretch in lower resolutions ?

I tried the "Enable GPU scaling " option in Catalyst but it seems to only work with windows desktop, didn't have any effect to the game.

Comment: I wonder if this is more suited to gaming.SE?

Answer (score 2):

Try your monitor's Menu button while in the game. There's probably an Info menu that tells you what resolution the PC is sending.

Assuming that's 1024x640, you need to choose how the monitor deals with resolutions smaller than its native resolution. When switching to a new resolution, old CRT monitors used to make it fill the screen, but LCD monitors often show it pixel-for-pixel with the rest of the pixels black. On my BenQ G2220HD, I choose Menu | Picture Advanced | Display Mode | Full.

You may also have a similar setting in your graphics card's driver (often on the task bar, or in Screen Resolution | Advanced Settings). On my Intel i3, it's Advanced Mode | Display | General Settings | Scaling | Scale Full Screen (or Maintain Aspect Ratio, if you choose a resolution at a different aspect ratio).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your resolution to 1024x600 in the control panel first. Does that scale or is there a black box? If that works, then run your game at the resolution you set in the control panel.

Answer (score 0):

In display settings, Select any resolution that is not the native one, then in **graphic properties**, choose Display and select **scale full screen**.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [IntegerScaler][1]. It scales up any window to match the screen's size and it was the only program that worked for me without the mouse messing up in my game.